# Logarithms and Haar integrals

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, topological-groups, haar-measure

The usual way to show that the topological groups $(\mathbb{R}_+^*,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R},+)$ are isomorphic is to consider, for instance, the function $\operatorname{ln}\colon \mathbb{R}_+^*\to\mathbb{R}$ which maps $x\mapsto \int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$. On the other hand

> every topological group $G$ *homeomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}$ must be
> *isomorphic* to $(\mathbb{R},+)$,

which it follows from [Theorem 2 in Bourbaki](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bQwhdmL6IjUC&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false), for instance.

Since every Hausdorff locally compact topological group $G$ has a Haar integral, i.e., a nontrivial left invariant positive linear functional $\mu\colon C_c(G)\to\mathbb{R}$, I would like to know if there is an adaptation of the logarithm construction that allows one to "simplifies" Bourbaki's proof of the quoted result above $-$ or if Haar integrals can be helpful in any other way in this context. References where this is done are welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; the approach to take becomes clear when you notice that $\frac{1}{t}dt$ is a Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}_+$.  So suppose we have a topological group structure $*$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with left Haar measure $\mu$; we wish to show this structure is isomorphic as a topological group to the usual one.  We may assume the identity element of the group structure is $0$.  Now define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\int_0^x d\mu$ (that is, $f(x)=\mu([0,x])$ if $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=-\mu([x,0])$ if $x<0$); I claim this is the desired isomorphism.  It is easy to see that this $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous, so it suffices to show that $f$ is a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},*)$ to $(\mathbb{R},+)$.  To show this, just observe that $$f(x*y)=\int_0^{x*y}d\mu=\int_0^xd\mu+\int_x^{x*y}d\mu=\int_0^xd\mu+\int_0^yd\mu=f(x)+f(y)$$ where the third equality uses the left-invariance of $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, after trying to fill the details, I got stuck at the second equality: it seems to depend on something like $[0,x*y]=[0,x]\cup [x,x*y]$, right? While this is certainly true when $*$ is the multiplication (and both $x$ and $y$ are $>0$), I don't see why it should hold in general. Am I missing something?

Comment: There are several cases to work through depending on the signs of everything but they are straightforward.  For instance, if $x*y<0<x$ then $\int_0^{x*y}d\mu$ is $-\mu([x*y,0])$ and $\int_0^xd\mu+\int_x^{x*y}d\mu$ is $\mu([0,x])-\mu([x*y,x])$ and these are equal since $\mu([x*y,x])=\mu([x*y,0])+\mu([0,x])$.

Comment: This is just the same as the elementary calculus verification that $\int_a^b+\int_b^c=\int_a^c$ in all possible cases for how $a,b,c$ might be arranged.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out again later. Thanks again. :)